# Enable auto-suggestion and it's layout in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm using Custom ListView with `Edittext`.

My problem is, while i'm typing in `EditText` , the Keypad does not show the Suggestion layout which is in Top of the Keypad.

my EditText code as,

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/remarks_eT"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@drawable/remarks_bg"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:maxLength="450"
        android:inputType="text|textMultiLine"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        android:textColor="@color/app_primary_color"
        android:textColorHint="@color/app_primary_color"
        android:hint="Type your Remarks"/>
```

How can i resolve this annoying issue.?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable auto suggestion for edit text by adding this line

```
 emailET.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
```

in java file and adding

```
android:autoText="true"
```

in xml although autoText is depreciated now, you can have nice suggestion on it by android studio :)